# Sorting arrays causes wrong data to be displayed into cells

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I've got an array of rooms I'm wanting to filter by usercount/topvotes sorta stuff.

I'm hitting buttons to trigger the filter changes and set a value to "CurrentSearch", reloading my tabledata, and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm checking the current currentsearch value and filtering the list accordingly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if currentSearch == "new" {
        self.PersonalSearchesList = PersonalSearchesList.sorted{ $0.users < $1.users }

        } else if currentSearch == "top" {

          self.PersonalSearchesList = self.PersonalSearchesList.sorted{ $0.latestUser < $1.latestUser }

        }
```

My images/labels load in perfectly fine before the filtering. On the initial load I'm setting currentSearch to "new" and it works perfectly. It's only once I start trying to swap between filters that things get funky. I'm getting random duplicates of cells, and while I'm swapping between the filters the incorrect loads stay consistent..as in the same duplicates of the same cells are being made/placed at the same spots.

I have it when I click on a cell the information for the cell is printed..and despite the cell information being loaded incorrectly the actual information is correct and the lists are ordered as they should be.

any ideas?

Comment: Never ever ever try to modify your data source on `cellForRowAtIndexPath `, that product very bad behavior and really wrong, you have to sort it before you reload your tableView

Comment: Moved where I'm sorting on the button taps then reloading the tableview and that worked perfectly. I saw sorting being done like this one time in a video and it stuck with me as the way to do it. Guess not haha. Apprecaite it man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
var currentSearch: String {
  didSet {
     // sort your array
    tableView?.reloadData() // reload data
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah perfect. That's exactly what I needed! On the initial load where can I do my sorting? I'm pulling my data from firebase so in viewdidload I can't just set currentSearch = to something cause the array won't necessarily be filled on load? When I'm appending into the array do I run the sort there so each time an item is added in it's going to sort or is that gonna be funky as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you will sort your every then it every time get sorted when you scroll your `tableview` or reload it. so sort your data somewhere else in other method and after successfully sorting reload your `tableview`.